# Не создается файл в Vs Code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

```
gg = input("Input: ")

with open("ggg.txt", 'w', encoding = 'utf-8') as file:
    file.write(gg)
    print("Done")
```

Весь код работает, но файл не создается, хотя *Done* выводится в терминал.
Я попробовал запустить данный код в **cmd**, и всё сработало, но почему не работает в **Vs Code**.
**Как это исправить?**

Comment: Для начала нужно понять, какая рабочая директория у Вас выставлена при запуске кода.

Comment: @ProtectchildrenofDonbas2014 и как это понять?

Comment: Ctrl+F5 нажмите и напишите, что работает, а что нет. "Не работает" - это не объяснение проблемы в деталях.